# mysql: Table alias doesn't exist

Tags: mysql

So I have a table in my database (which I'll call Test). The table is named Items, and has an int column named itemID and a decimal(8, 2) column named currently. They represent a unique ID for an item and the current bid price on an item, respectively. The currently column is able to be NULL because there may not have been a bid on an item yet.

My goal is to get the itemID of the item with the highest current bid that has at least one bid. I have a mysql query that looks as follows:

```
select itemID
from (select itemID from Items where numBids > 0) as b
where currently = (select max(currently) from b);
```

When I execute this in mysql, I get an error that says:

```
ERROR 1146 (42S02): Table 'Test.b' doesn't exist
```

Can anyone explain what's going on here? I haven't used mysql in a while so I'm rusty. Do I have to do a join of Items with itself in order to accomplish something like this? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

The alias "b" is not being seen by the last subquery. Insted to use that complicated query use

```
SELECT itemID
FROM Items
WHERE numBids > 0
ORDER BY currently DESC 
LIMIT 1
```

To handle the situation where multiple items have the highest current bid:

```
SELECT itemID
FROM Items
WHERE numBids > 0
  AND currently =
      ( SELECT MAX(currently)
        FROM Items
        WHERE numBids > 0 
      )
```

Comment: Ah, this is much simpler! I never seem to be able to think of them in these clean ways. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I do have a question though. This doesn't handle the situation where multiple items have the highest current bid. Is there a simple workaround to get all items with the highest current bid?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you cannot use the `b` inside the `select` of the `where` clausole.

Comment: Ah, thank you. Does this require a total rethinking of the structure of my query?

Comment: Try select b.itemID from Items b where b.numBids > 0 and b.currently = (select max(a.currently) from Items a where a.itemID = b.itemID and a.numBids > 0);

Comment: carpii: Thanks, but that query takes too long to execute (at least on my machine).